# Response.redirect () behaviour

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am facing this similar Thread abort exception in my .aspx page(asp.net 1.1), it is working currently in IIS 6.0.

After I migrate application to Asp.net 4.5 it occurs in new application.

This behaviour varies between IIS6.0 and IIS 8.5 with .Net 4.0 app pool.

Please clarify.

Comment: What's the issue exactly? What code causes it?

Comment: in the q/a that I have give you there are example on how to use the exception and what is the reason behind of it.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks. I am clarified with the suggested code fix. But wanted to know why it is not occuring in win2003, IIS 6.0 version with .Net 1.1 framework